# after loading html in native webview worklight js and css not getting linked

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have created one class in native ios where which is having header, footer and webview. So i am passing xslt, xml data as a paramter to that class and after getting parameter it loading xslt in webview.[image]

Here u can see header footer is in blue color and webview data is showing in between header and footer. This is common class which is in native. I am calling that class by using `WL.nativePage.show(classname, callback, paramter)`

Problem Description- i have one login.xslt as a login page which i am calling initially in app.js file like this .

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    WL.NativePage.show(WebviewClass, BackFromNative, {param :'loginPage.xslt', param2:'<DATA></DATA>'});
}
```

Now if i am doing like this , am not able to call any function from app.js file even i am not able to call adapter which i have defined in app.js file. What is solution for this because all the js and css file is in app.html file , i won't required to include in every html file right.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the native page first. Are you returning back to the webpage from the native page? Is your "BackFromNative" callback being called?

Comment: Yes backfromnative is workking, why becoz we are just finishing the activity in native and passing control back to hybrid as per worklight docs But what about html in native webview. I am not able to call adapter from there and any other functionality from worklight.

Comment: Can you please provide a snippet as to what you are trying?

Comment: Example:From index.html i am calling WL.nativePage.show(class,callbk,param), in this class I am loading same index.html in native webview. Same thing doing cardova intially. Why I am not able to use same functionality in native webview.

Comment: If you load the index.html from the native webview that will not initialize the Worklight framework.If you are trying to make adapter procedure call then the options would be  make the call from the call back after returning from the native page or use native Worklight invoke procedure API's to achieve that functionality natively.

Comment: So that is the issue, because we have mix hybrid application where we have native page and in that we have hybrid page where we are doing so many transaction and method already there in javascript file which we are not able to call from native webview, how can we achieve this.

Comment: You cannot load a Worklight webview into native webview.